# how to display all active connections in TcpServer using poco library

Tags: c++, poco-libraries, tcpserver

I am trying to work with the poco library. I started with an example [tcpserver](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/master/Net/samples/tcpserver/src/tcpserver.cpp). I need to display all active connections, but I did not find the required method in the library classes. how can display all active connections?

Comment: You can call `currentConnections` to get the number of current connections, but I am guessing you would like the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not currently part of the `TCPServer` class.

You could request an enhancement here https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/issues to `TCPServer` to add a way to access the connection objects.

Or you could define your own factory like `TCPServerConnectionFactory` to do it in a derived factory.